# Where is my invalid character?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

**Every time I want to create a table in sql developer:**

```
create table tabelle(
dgeh emp.sal%type)
```

**I get this error:**

911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
     *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
            letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
            character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
            any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
            (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
            delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
            Reference Manual.
     *Action:

**It's driving my crazy! Where is my invalid character? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: The percent sign: %

Comment: Oh god I figured out I can't use the %type as variable type before the declare part. Thanks for the answer thought.